# Subscribe to a subset of keys in Redis

Tags: java, redis

I'm writing a Spring boot app which has a web socket (web flux) endpoint. Redis is running in the background holding key/value pairs. The values are updated every few seconds.

Clients make calls to the endpoint mentioned above, and they're supposed to receive key/value pairs which they requested, whenever there is a new value for any of those keys.

I'm wondering if it is possible to subscribe to a subset of keys which Redis holds, in such a way that the endpoint controller gets notified whenever the value for one those keys changes.

Real world example: A stock screening app. A client makes a request to the endpoint, requesting to get live feed of prices of a few symbols. The latest values are stored in Redis.

Comment: Have you looked into Keyspace Notifications - https://redis.io/topics/notifications

Comment: Yes, but it was not clear to me if I can: 1. Subscribe to a set of keys 2. and the set to be dynamic, so user can change it each time it makes a request

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this challenge with Redis (and I assume Java and Spring support them all).

Your question appears to be about [Keyspace Notifications (KSN)](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) and [PubSub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub). Note that PubSub is a shoot-and-forget (at-most-once delivery) messaging bus.

Assuming you had activated KSN, you can [`PSUBSCRIBE`](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe) to any supported pattern, specifically these that correspond to the "set" of keys you're interested in.

To make it "dynamic", you can call [`PUNSUBSCIBE`](https://redis.io/commands/psubscribe) and then `PSUBSCRIBE` again.